# Setting small notification icon background color while app is not running

Tags: android, notifications, background-color

I am setting the **background color of small icon** in notification, using `setColor` but it only displays the color when app is running. As soon as I **close** the app and send notification again, it does not show that color. I am using following snippet to set the background color of small icon.

```
setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.black))
```

This is how it looks like when **app is running**.

[image: Background color when app is running.]

**After closing the app** and sending notification again, it looks like this

[image: Background color after closing the app.]

*Note: I am testing it on Android M (6.0.1) *

Comment: 01. setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.black))
Hope this is written in a Service. You need to debug the Service.

02. If you make a .png Image of the color, which you want, then may be you can fix this. "You can atleast try."

Comment: Yes it's from service. What's relation with service? Service is working fine.

Comment: Have  you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You will get the color applied if you just pass the color value in notification object from server like this:

```
"notification": {
    "title":"",
    "body": "Body",
    "sound":"true",
    "color":"red"     
}
```

you can even pause the hex code in direct to the color field.